# Custom validation using AddModelError for child viewmodel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-validation

I'm having to do some custom validation on a child viewmodel, adding any issues to the `ModelState` using `ModelState.AddModelError()`. However I'm presented with an issue trying to get the correct property key.

My parent viewmodel contains N `ChildViewModels`, where I'm validating a child property:

```
public class ParentViewModel {
    ...
    public List<ChildViewModel> Children = new List<ChildViewModel>();
}

public class ChildViewModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public int PropertyToValidate { get; set; }
}
```

In the view, I iterate over the `ChildViewModel` collection and display a partial view for each:

```
@foreach(var child in Model.Children)
    Html.RenderPartial("EditorTemplates/ChildViewModel", child);
```

This results in the property controls and validation placeholders of each child being rendered as follows, with a unique `Name` prefix:

```
<input type="number" name="Children[83d5b826-f8f0-47fe-8985-c45debd1d846].PropertyToValidate">
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Children[83d5b826-f8f0-47fe-8985-c45debd1d846].PropertyToValidate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

**My question is, how do I get `Children[83d5b826-f8f0-47fe-8985-c45debd1d846].PropertyToValidate` to use as a key when adding to the `ModelStateDictionary`?**

In my controller I have a collection of invalid `ChildViewModel` and I've tried adding them to the `ModelStateDictionary` as follows:

```
invalidChildViewModels.ForEach(x =>
    ModelState.AddModelError(
        ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(x),
        "My custom validation error message"));
```

But this results in a blank key being added and as such the validation message doesn't get displayed.

Comment: I assume your using the `BeginCollectionItem()` method which is generating a `Guid` for the indexer, which means you cannot (it will be a different `Guid` when you return the view. What are you needing to do that cannot be done on the client?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, in the partial view all the controls are wrapped in a `@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Children")) {}`. The validation requires a database round trip (based on aggregate counts) which has to be done on submission of the form.

Comment: Could you not handke the submit event, and make an ajax call to do the server side processing and then return the errors back as a `JsonResult`?

Comment: Yes I suppose that's one way of resolving it, however the application has zero client side validation logic, it's all done on the back end. If I can avoid restructuring a large part of the front-end I'd be very happy.